# Android: Usual way to stop and log an unrecoverable error

Tags: android, exception, crash, report

What is the usual way on Android to stop my application if it has reached an unrecoverable error.

finish() will not do it, since it wont stop any running services or threads. Furthermore I would like to inform the user what has happend and please him to send an error log.

As far as I googled, it seems like there is no way to close my application and open a special crashreport activity or something else to show the user whats going on or send a crash log.

Comment: When your app has an **uncaught** runtime exception, the whole vm is shut down for your app. Services, threads, etc are gone. You can implement an [UncaughtExceptionHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) to log these things however. Or use ACRA, it has more features.

Comment: @Max Mustermann you can implement you own logging. To implement this check https://github.com/ajaysaini-sgvu/CrashReport

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should throw unhandled runtime exception. In such case android will kill all your process. Also I suggest you to use [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/). This library will help you to get crash report (via email, google docs, etс.) and it can show customizable error dialog to a user.

Comment: How does this work? I mean, how is it able to display views after the application has crashed? I couldn't find anything in the androdi documentation related to uncaught exception handlers.

Comment: Check the basic setup guide - [ACRA - Basic Setup](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetup)

Answer (score 1):

You should check this out. This could be your solution.
[ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra)

Check the basic setup guide to start using the library. [ACRA - Basic Setup](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetup)

Answer (score 1):

While ACRA is an okay solution, if you want to implement your own logging of unhandled exceptions try [Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29).  That way you can get any exceptions that are thrown and not caught, and log them the way you like.  You need to implement [Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) and pass it to that method.

With an Activity, it would look something like this in onCreate():

```
getMainLooper().getThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new MyUncaughtExceptionHandler());
```

Comment: Thanks for that bit of code. Actually that is what I was looking for. But only because I thought ACRA is just a framework and you have to do much more UI stuff to get it working. I think Leonidos answer is more usefull if you find this question via google.